# Hibernate remove outOfMemory

Tags: hibernate

We use Hibernate in our application to manage transactions in DB. When I launch a java program to remove entities  in database(up to 600 entities), I have an OutOfMemory (.The program takes in paramaters a list of ids to remove. Before removing an entity, I do a find with its id.

I suppose that allouing memory to all entities cause the OutOfMemory (before the auto flush)
I have thought to add the evict() instructions after each delete or a flush... but its not recommended for performance.

Here's the stacktrace :

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
   at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2882)
   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:100)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:515)
at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:306)
at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:77)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.ClobAccessor.getString(ClobAccessor.java:239)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CClobAccessor.getString(T4CClobAccessor.java:70)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getString(OracleResultSetImpl.java:397)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getString(OracleResultSet.java:1515)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getString(DelegatingResultSet.java:263)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getString(DelegatingResultSet.java:263)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarcharTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarcharTypeDescriptor.java:61)
```

Comment: Please, post the code sample where entities removal is performed

Answer (score -1):

Here the snippet which causes error :

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
    public void remove(List<Configuration> listConfiguration){
        for (Configuration configuration : listConfiguration) {
            configuration = findById(configuration);
            configurationDao.remove(configuration);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why you want to add this as an answer to the question? you should update your question and add whatever information needed. Please delete this.